# Altair "Cannot find a selection named 'selectorXXX' " error

Tags: altair, streamlit

I want to make it possible select a legend category and have it highlighted in an Altair chart.  However, I get the `"Error: Cannot find a selection named "selector015"`." message.  I've seen other references to it when the coder forgets the `.add_selection()` command to the chart, but I have it included here.

Furthermore, when I comment all three references to `selection3` out (in the definition, color condition (swap it with the other color line below that does not depend on selection), and .add_selection), the error **still** appears.  I don't understand how even commenting it out doesn't fix the error.

```
selection3 = alt.selection_multi(fields=['subscribed'], bind='legend')

IF = alt.Chart(df[filt]).mark_circle().encode(
    alt.X('subscription_cost', title="log( Journal Cost )", axis=alt.Axis(format='$,.2r')),    #grouped thousands with two significant digits
    alt.Y('IF%', title='Instant Fill %'),
    tooltip=(['title','subscription_cost','IF%']),
    color=alt.condition(selection3, alt.Color('subscribed:N', scale=subscribed_colorscale), alt.value('lightgray'))
    #color=alt.Color('subscribed:N', scale=subscribed_colorscale)
    ).interactive().properties(
        height = 400,
        title={
            "text": ['Instant Fill % vs. Journal Subscription Cost'],
            "subtitle": ["Which journals increase Instant Fill % the most"],
            "color": "black",
            "subtitleColor": "gray"
        }
    ).add_selection(selection3)
st.altair_chart(IF, use_container_width=True)
```

[Error message] (https://ibb.co/1fYNVm1)

Comment: If the error still appears after removing all the selections from the definition, I suspect the issue is that you're dispalying an earlier problematic version of the chart  rather than the one you just created (check your variable names and restart the runtime). If you'd like more help, I'd suggest adding a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) – your original code snippet is close, but has references to undefined variables.

Comment: Thanks, I haven't had time to get back around to this yet, but I do have several `selection` definitions in the script. A reused variable name may be causing problems here.